# iPhone is missing a hanfdul of contacts

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts

I noticed that one of my contacts (my dad!) suddenly disappeared from my iPhone, in the middle of the day. I don't remember doing anything or deleting it.

I looked online on iCloud.com, and saw that my contact is still there. Also I've noticed that on iCloud it says 532 contacts, while my iPhone says 528 contacts. So a total of 4 contacts are probably missing (not sure which).

I've tried waiting (overnight), restarting, and also I've disabled iCloud Contacts syncing completely -reboot- and re-enabled it. Still 528 and no Dad...

I've also tried sync with iTunes (event though I only use iCloud) and removing the entire iCloud account and adding it again.

As a sidenote, the Contacts app on the Mac seems fine, 532 contacts.

EDIT: another interesting twist, if in the Message app I manually type my father's phone number, I can see his name appearing in the autocomplete suggestions! Yet once I send it, only the number shows, the name is not there anymore...

Comment: Try adding a new contact with exact the same details manually. It seems 4 of your total Contact-cards are corrupted according to your iPhone. Let us know if manually adding a new one fixes your issue.

Comment: Have you tried syncing your device with iTunes yet?

Comment: Yes, nothing new. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Make sure you are not perhaps only viewing some groups on your iphone.

Comment: Yes I've checked that - Showing All Contacts...

Comment: I've cheated: I've exported 2 contacts I've identified as missing, emailed them to myself, deleted from icloud and re-added from the phone. It works for now. I'm still missing 2 that I haven't identified...